# How to get Google search to return links including query strings

Tags: javascript, php, css, sitemap, google-search-console

Can anyone tell me how to get Google search results to return a url containing a query string?  A sample from the project I'm working on can be seen here:

http://www.uvm.edu/~chem/?Page=./faculty/landry.php&SM=submenu_people.html

but a Google search returns a link to:

https://www.uvm.edu/~chem/faculty/landry.php

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

ALTERNATIVELY...

Is there some (non-hackish) php/js that can automatically direct a browser to the url containing the query string if the one w/out the query string is entered?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You can get it by window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a whole section in Webmaster Tools that includes URL parameters that allows you to control how these are handled.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters